# How to test onClose: () => window.close() in react - Jest

Tags: jestjs

Below is my piece of code where I am trying to set default props for my React component.

```
myHeader.defaultProps = {
onClose: () => window.close(),
hideCloseButton: false,
};
```

I tried writing test case to cover this, but
onClose: () => window.close(),

line is not getting covered, how can I test this line. Can you please suggest.